# Angular JS update ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to write time tracker with angular js.
I have next HTML code

```
            <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>{{task.name}}</td>
                <td class="text-right">{{task.time}}</td>
            </tr>
```

I have model Task

```
    function Task(name, time) {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;

        this.incrementTime = function($scope) {
            this.time++;
        }
    }
```

So I want to update task every second in controller
something like this

```
function TaskController($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.tasks = [];

    $scope.addTask = function() {
        var task = new Task($scope.task, 0);
        $interval( task.incrementTime, 1000 );
        $scope.tasks.unshift(task);
        $scope.task = '';
    }
}
```

but my table dont update task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gruffy Bunny mentioned, you should use $interval instead of setInterval. $interval is a wrapper for setInterval, but the basic thing that $interval does that setInterval doesn't, is wrapping callback invocation with $scope.apply(yourCallback), which starts a digest cycle that will dirty check your scope models and eventually will update your view.

Comment: 1. You don't need form and ng-submit, just use ng-click. 2. you're using an old version of angular which didn't have $interval, use the recent version.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interval) service and pass the incrementTime function to the interval

```
function TaskController($scope, $interval) {
   $scope.tasks = []

   $scope.addTask = function() { 
     //add task 
     var task = new Task($scope.task, 0);
     $interval( task.incrementTime, 1000 );
     $scope.tasks.push(task);
   }
}
```

and tweak the Task constructor so that that incrementTime references the correct time variable:

```
function Task(name, time) {
    var self = this;

    this.name = name;
    this.time = time;

    this.incrementTime = function() {
        self.time++;
    }
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/bvqBH/)</kbd>

Comment: It's still not working for me
http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=streamer&s=GYw5zvmCIPpQoxHC

Comment: The fiddle works - the plunker incrementTime is using the wrong 'this'

Answer (score 0):

you're setting up `var task` as a new Task, not updating the existing one.  Something like `$scope.task.incrementTime()` is what you want

Comment: But I have model Task
function Task(name, time) { ... }

Comment: You're creating a new Task object and altering that, not altering the $scope.task like you're wanting to.  If you want to use `new Task` you need to add this new `task` object to `$scope.tasks`

Comment: Yes I added $scope.tasks.unshift(task), but table still not updated, if I changed time